# create a map to write and run a ruby script

Tags: ruby, vim

Wondering if there's a way to create a vim shortcut so I don't have to type `w ! ruby` every time I test some code. I know you can add maps to your .vimrc file, and I'm looking for adding the keyword :wr to save and run some code. However, I'm not sure which mode these commands are: visual, command-line, normal, etc. There's different forms of mapping for these modes: vmap, cmap, nmap, etc. Anyone know how I should proceed?

The contents of my .vimrc are as follows:

```
syntax on
set cindent
set nu
colorscheme delek
set hlsearch
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2
nmap <F6> :w<CR>:!ruby %<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mapping for different modes is as below

1. nmap : Normal or escape mode.
2. imap : Insert mode
3. vmap : Visual mode

You should be creating an `nmap` to run the command by aging a line like below to your `.vimrc`

```
nmap <F6> :w<CR>:!ruby %<CR>
```

The above code will map function key `F6` to in normal or escape mode to first save your code and then run the current file with `ruby` command.

Details for key mapping in Vim : [Mapping keys in Vim - Tutorial (Part 1)](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29)

Comment: Thanks, I found that tutorial. That's where I found all the different forms of mapping. I've modified your command in as many ways as I can think of and every time I get a `E488: Trailing characters` error. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Can you update your question with contents of your `.vimrc`? I guess you are using `autocmd` in your `.vimrc`. That error is related to `autocmd`.